# 3D shearing w. r. t. x-axis

Tags: graphics3d, rotation, geometric-transform

Shearing in $X$ axis is achieved by using the following shearing equations-

X_new = X_old, Y_new = Y_old + Sh_y × X_old, Z_new = Z_old + Sh_z × X_old

My question is during Y_new and Z_new calculations why Sh_y,Sh_z is multiplying with X_old respectively, why not any other constant? Every books, websites mention just formula not the reason.

Can anyone give pictorial representations how shearing is happening with explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
dy = 0.1; dz = 0.1;
orig = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}];
sheared = 
  Line[{{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 
      0, 0}, {1, dy, dz}, {1, 1 + dy, dz}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0,
       0, 0}, {1, dy, dz}, {1, dy, 1 + dz}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 
      0}}, {{0, 0, 1}, {1, dy, 1 + dz}, {1, 1 + dy, 1 + dz}, {0, 1, 
      1}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 1 + dy, dz}, {1, 1 + dy, 
      1 + dz}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 1 + dy, dz}, {1,
       1 + dy, 1 + dz}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}}];
Graphics3D[{
  {Opacity[0.5], orig}
  , Red, Thickness[0.005], shared
  }, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: please intuition little bit. It's pictorial representations, I want to understand concepts.

Comment: Your description says, that the y and z coordinates of every point are changed by a constant (shy,shz) times the x coordinate. If you want to know more you could e.g. look up: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_(physics)

Comment: But question is why x_old?why not any other constant?

Comment: Your formula are a very special case. The general case is more complicate. You need a text about "Mechanics of deformable solids" or "Strain and Stress" Besides shear you will also have to deal with compression.